# Run node js application without port

Tags: node.js, express, http, https, tcp

I wants to run my application without assigning any port on my current IP address on port 80. How it will possible.

Comment: Have you try setting the port 80 (instead of 3000) for exemple...

Comment: then you need a web /proxy server like Nginx or apache. where you can define your server which will listen on port 80 and will pass the request to your nodejs app which will be listening on 3000

Comment: look at you file bin/www, the port is set to listening on port 3000. Why just don't you set it to 80 ?

Comment: No public IP addresses on Stack Overflow, please. Because cybercreeps. You may wish to delete that comment.

Comment: I appreciate your answers I have removed public IP from  comment. I have also tried to set port 3000 to 80 in bin/www file but its not working.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If your node.js application is a web server, you cannot remove the port. No port, no web server. Trying to make a web server without a port is like trying to make a locomotive with no railroad.

You **can use the default port** however. When users give browsers URLs without ports, they automatically apply the default port. For URLs like `http://example.com/` or `http://10.11.12.13/` the default port is 80. For `https://example.com` it's 443, and you need to use the `https` server class.

So, you can make your server listen on port 80.

In development you will run into a problem with this approach. On OSX, Linux, and other UNIX-derived OSs, only the privileged (`root`) user can run servers that use port numbers less than 1024. The typical development cycle of edit / run / test is a huge hassle, and a security hole, when you need privileges to run. That's why the node.js examples use port 3000.

In production, many people use nginx as a reverse proxy server to relay http requests from port 80 or https requests from port 443 to your node.js server at port 3000. You can read about how to do that; it's far beyond the scope of a Stack Overflow answer,